# How to loop through indeed job pages using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to make a selenium python script to collect data from each job in an indeed job search. I can easily get the data from the first and second page. The problem I am running into is while looping through the pages, the script only clicks the next page and the previous page, in that order. Going from page 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2 -> ect. I know it is doing this because both the next and previous button have the same class name. So when I redeclare the webelement variable when the page uploads, it hits the previous button because that is the first location of the class in the stack. I tried making it always click the next button by using the xpath, but I still run into the same errors. I would inspect the next button element, and copy the full xpath. my code is below, I am using python 3.7.9 and pip version 21.2.4

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
HTTPS = "https://"

# hard coded data to test
siteDomain = "indeed.com"
jobSearch = "Software Developer"
locationSearch = "Richmond, VA"

listOfJobs = []

def if_exists_by_id(id):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id(id)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True


def if_exists_by_class_name(class_name):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name(class_name)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True


def if_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True


def removeSpaces(strArray):

    newjobCounter = 0
    jobCounter = 0

    for i, word in enumerate(strArray):

        jobCounter += 1

        if strArray[i].__contains__("\n"):
            strArray[i] = strArray[i].replace("\n", " ")
        if strArray[i].__contains__("new"):
            newjobCounter += 1

        print(strArray[i] + "\n")

    if newjobCounter == 0:
        print("Unfortunately, there are no new jobs for this search")
    else:
        print("With " + str(newjobCounter) + " out of " + str(jobCounter) + " new jobs!")

    return strArray

try:

    # Goes to Site
    driver.get(HTTPS + siteDomain)

    # obtains access to elements from website
    searchJob = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
    searchLocation = driver.find_element_by_name("l")

    # clear text field
    searchJob.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "a", Keys.BACK_SPACE)
    searchLocation.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "a", Keys.BACK_SPACE)

    # inputs values into website elements
    searchJob.send_keys(jobSearch)
    searchLocation.send_keys(locationSearch)

    # presses button to search
    searchLocation.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    # Begin looping through pages
    pageList = driver.find_element_by_class_name("pagination")
    page = pageList.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
    numPages = 0

    for i,x in enumerate(page):

        time.sleep(1)

        # checks for popup, if there is popup, exit out and sleep
        if if_exists_by_id("popover-x"):
            driver.find_element_by_id("popover-x").click()
            time.sleep(1)


        # increment page counter variabke
        numPages += 1

        # obtains data in class name value
        jobCards = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("jobCard_mainContent")

        # prints number of jobs returned
        print(str(len(jobCards)) + " jobs in: " + locationSearch)

        # inserts each job into list of jobs array
        # commented out to make debugging easier
        # for jobCard in jobCards:
        #    listOfJobs.append(jobCard.text)

        # supposed to click the next page, but keeps alternating
        # between next page and previous page
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("np").click()

        print("On page number: " + str(numPages))

    # print(removeSpaces(listOfJobs))

except ValueError:
    print(ValueError)

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, also if I am implementing bad coding practices in the structure of the script please let me know as I am trying to learn as much as possible! :)

Comment: You can use Beautifulsoup to scrape this. No need to use Selenium.

Comment: @Ram I ended up getting a list of links from the page buttons on the bottom of the page and looping through the performing actions on each 'page'

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code.. the thing is there are 2 'np' class elements when we go to the 2nd page.. what you can do is for first time use `find_element_by_class_name('np')` and for all the other time use `find_elements_by_class_name('np')[1]` that will select the next button.. and you can use `find_elements_by_class_name('np')[0]` for the previous button if needed. Here is the code!

```
    if i == 0:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("np").click()
    else:
        driver.find_elements_by_class_name("np")[1].click()
```

Just replace the line `driver.find_element_by_class_name("np").click()` with the code snippet above.. I have tested it and it worked like a charm.

Also i am not as experienced as the other devs here.. But i am glad if i could help you. (This is my first answer ever on stackoverflow)